# ¿Cómo mostrar todos los resultados de una tabla excepto los que coincidan con los resultados de otra tabla?

Tags: sql

Quisiera saber cómo se puede hacer una consulta de la siguiente manera: Mostrar todas las de una tabla de la columna llamada "numeroPregunta":

Tabla: preguntasAuxiliarAdministrativo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no mostrar las que coincidan con los numeroPregunta de esta otra tabla llamada "respuestasTestUsuario' cuya columna "respuestaCorrectas" sea menor a 4

Tabla: respuestasTestUsuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT preguntasAuxiliarAdministrativo.numeroPregunta 
FROM preguntasAuxiliarAdministrativo 
INNER JOIN respuestasTestUsuario 
ON preguntasAuxiliarAdministrativo.numeroPregunta=respuestasTestUsuario.numeroPregunta 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT respuestasTestUsuario.numeroPregunta 
         FROM respuestasTestUsuario     
         WHERE respuestasTestUsuario.respuestasCorrectas<3 
         )
```

El resultado me muestra 0 filas, entonces no está bien la consulta. Y debería devolver 12,9,7,6,5,3...

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Puedes hacer algo así por ejemplo: **`SELECT p.numeroPregunta 
FROM   preguntasAuxiliarAdministrativo p
LEFT OUTER JOIN respuestasTestUsuario r
  ON (p.numeroPregunta = r.numeroPregunta)
  WHERE r.numeroPregunta IS NULL AND r.respuestasCorrectas <= 3`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario relacionar ambas tablas con JOIN.
Buscar en la primera tabla los valores que no estén en la lista, y la lista son las preguntas que tienen menos de 4 correctas en la segunda tabla.

```
   SELECT numeroPregunta 
   FROM preguntasAuxiliarAdministrativo 
   WHERE numeroPregunta 
         NOT IN (SELECT numeroPregunta 
                  FROM respuestasTestUsuario     
                  WHERE respuestasCorrectas < 4  )
```

Comment: Con `LEFT OUTER JOIN`es mucho más rápido, si tiene los índices correctamente claro está.

Comment: si las tablas tienen una llave primari y una foránea que las vincula, hacer uso de JOIN es lo lógico y natural

Answer (score 0):

No te hace falta el NOT EXISTS, al hacer el join ya tienes las dos tablas relacionadas, con lo que simplemente cambiando la clausula del WHERE por algo como esto ya deberia funcionarte:

```
WHERE respuestasTestUsuario.respuestasCorrectas < 4
```

Por cierto que la condición de menor que "<" es estricta, con lo que si pones 3 no te devolverá aquellos resultados con "respuestasCorrectas" = 3. O pones < 4 o <= 3.

Comment: No. Él quiere los que **no estén** en la otra tabla, de ahí su intento con `NOT EXISTS`, aunque lo más performante es usar un `LEFT OUTER JOIN ` en este caso.

Comment: "Pero no mostrar las que coincidan con los numeroPregunta de esta otra tabla llamada "respuestasTestUsuario' cuya columna "respuestaCorrectas" sea menor a 4". Yo entiendo que lo que quiere no son los que no estén, sino los que cumplan la condición dada.

Comment: Ohhh ahora que lo dices así puede que tengas razón, quizá fui yo quien entendí mal entonces. En ese caso, propondría esto: **`SELECT p.numeroPregunta FROM preguntasAuxiliarAdministrativo p INNER JOIN respuestasTestUsuario r ON (p.numeroPregunta = r.numeroPregunta) WHERE r.respuestasCorrectas <= 3`**